# Windows 7 IE8 Font Size Issue with em

Tags: html

When viewing my application thru Windows7 IE8, I noticed that the Font Size for H1 and H2 Tags are completely off and too large.

This causes the Titles to wrap and wrecking everything below it.

The Font Sizes are set to em and not px, and Im not sure if this is causing the issue.
font-size: 2.7em;

I have XP w/ IE8 and the application looks fine.  I also checked this w/ MS Expression Superview, and it checked fine in all of the browsers.

http://www.davincispainting.com

In this ScreenShot the H1 & H2 Titles appear correct.  However, if this is viewed with Windows7 IE8 there exists the problem.

[image]

Here are the Style Classes for H1 & H2 Tags:

```
#mid-feature h1 {
color: #FF0000;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 2.7em;
}
#midlower-feature h2 {
color: #0C2A55;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size: 2em;
/*text-align:center;*/
}
```

Comment: Looks okay to me on Win7+IE9. If it's so critical to the layout of your page, why not use px instead of em?

Comment: I have known em to cause weird behavior.  The em represents (in theory) the width of an uppercase M in the current font. I believe historically it's been used to measure the size of text given a particular font.  But setting a font size in terms of ems is recursive -- how do you know what the em is until *after* you set the font size?

Comment: @Bala I could try to use px.  It looked fine to me too, until I saw this on my friend's computer.   Im thinking that the issue could be with the screen resolution of their computer.

Comment: @David so your saying that it makes better sense to just use px?

Comment: Or try @HackedByChinese's proposed solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to include a CSS reset page *before* your CSS. The purpose of a reset is to get the default state of all elements into a consistent state for all browsers, so your particular CSS styling has a better chance of looking the same on each browser.

[YUI has a reset you can use](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/).

Comment: Browsers have different default CSS for many HTML tags. A good reset insures that all browsers are starting at the same place.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's attention into this, I realize that this wasn't the most elegant issue to solve, Thank you again.